# Best Solution for Server alerting system through SMS

Tags: windows, monitoring, sms

We got the 2 GSM modem that use COM port, We want to monitoring our servers and switches, and when these servers and switches reset or shutdown it send us sms and send the status of these.

we currently use Solarwinds for monitoring but the SMS system doesnt work! so what is the best software and application that we can use?

we want to find the application that send us both up and down status of devices.

Comment: Based on your response to quanta and the tags chosen, you may want to consider revising your question to more explicitly state what you are trying to do, and what sort of solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Nagios.

Comment: we are using windows server 2003, we had gsm modem

Comment: @user19049: Even if you are using Windows server, you can install the nagios monitoring server on another Linux box. To monitor the Windows server, you can install nrpe server. There is a version can work on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using gammu as sms gateway and cacti with plugin monitor and thold to monitor server uptime.

Answer (score 0):

Try pagerduty.com !